# Turning image into grayscale following pointer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cursor

I'm trying to turn a background-image into grayscale by overlapping a colored background with the same image modified in B&W with photoshop.
The colored image should turn into grayscale following the cursor.
It's simpler to explain with this quick view:
http://jsbin.com/dediqefero/1/edit?html,css,js,output

I've set the background image in both of the divs, but in the b&w one I can't insert a 100% height so the image can't fit to the other one, neither can be responsively full screen.
How can I change the background-image dimensions to let the B&W one fit to the colored one?

Thanks all ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you've used `center center` in the positioning of `.content`, and you have used `background-size` too.

If you want to do these types of adjustments, you need to apply them to both the background `.content` and foreground `.grey` which you can't do in *CSS* - you'd need to calculate your own offsets etc using *JavaScript*.

Testing *background-size* with pixel values makes it seem unstable and wobble around as the cursor moves.

You can calculate the centre pretty easily though

```
// after .content exists
var dh = content.offsetHeight,
    dw = content.offsetWidth,
    ih = 1004,
    iw = 1599,
    _h, _w;

_h = (ih / 2) - (dh / 2); // centre image in div vertical
_w = (iw / 2) - (dw / 2); // centre image in div horizontal

content.style.backgroundPosition = -_w + 'px ' + -_h + 'px';
```

Remember to store `_h` and `_w` so you can do the same adjustment on `.gray` with e.g.

```
gray.style.top = e.y - 50 + 'px';
gray.style.left = e.x - 50 + 'px';
gray.style.backgroundPosition = (50 - e.x - _w) + 'px ' + (50 - e.y - _h) + 'px';
```

Quick [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/v4k4b3f2/) (I skipped the position of `.content` correction because I wrote it in vanilla)

Comment: The correction I skipped is about _8 px_ in both _x_ and _y_ in the fiddle on my screen, but that's just that page. You'd need to calculate the offset dynamically if you want the code to work on any page. You seem to already know how to do this in _jQuery_ ^^ Vanilla involves looping with `.offsetParent`